# if row equals parameter from url

Tags: php

my url i have a parameter called uid

in my sql i have

```
Select * from users Where uid = {$_GET['uid']}
```

now I have my while loop

```
while (($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) != false) {
    $uid = $row['uid'];
}
```

every thing is fine to this point. what i want is if the uid in the database does not equal the $_GET from parameter redirect.

```
if ($uid == $_GET['uid']) {    
        return true;    
    } else {    
        redirect(ROOT_URI);
    }
```

what i am trying to prevent is modifying uid in the url. that if the uid does not exists it will redirect.

Comment: Use `!=` ... `if ($uid != $_GET['uid']) { ...}else { redirect.... }`

Comment: @S.I i have tried that but it don't redirect

Comment: Do you mean "if the uid does not exists in the GET parameter?" Or in the database?

Comment: Seems like redirect declaration isn't correct

Comment: @Rax  Weber if the get id doesnot match the db uid redirect

Comment: You also probably want to use prepared statements

Comment: intialize the $uid=''; at top of the code

Comment: uid is unique id ???? then why that while loop ?? just count the if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){   return true;  }else { redirect(ROOT_URI);  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply you can do like this

```
$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($rowcount != 0)
{
return true;
}
else
{
redirect(ROOT_URI);
}
```

since if the uid is in the table mysqli_num_rows doesn't return 0

Answer (score 1):

Use this. I've included some comments as explanation to what I am doing.

```
$x = 0; //checker

while (($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) != false) {
    if($uid == $row['uid']){
      $x = 1; //logic is if there is a match, $x will become 1, else it will stay at 0 value
    }
}

//now check the value of $x

if ($x == 1){
  //there is a match
  return true; 
}
else{
  //there is no match
  redirect(ROOT_URI); 
}
```

Comment: Down vote? Appreciate it so much. Thanks! And good luck to whoever you are. :)

Answer (score 0):

To redirect in PHP, you can use the `header()` function:

```
header("Location: your_url");
```

Comment: I already have header redirect there the problem is if they change the uid in the url and if the uid in not in the db it shows a blank page

Comment: And an `exit(0);` statemenr in case you use Internet Explorer

Comment: @Case So what do you want to happen if the uid does not exist?

Comment: @Rex Weber if the value in parameter does not equal the uid in the database redirect. if the url is example.com/033  and they type example.com/0333 if 0333 don't exists redirect.

Comment: So you said it would redirect. Then the problem is your URL, because you said it would redirect to a blank page if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Your sql query is wrong. Try with this one:

```
Select uid from users Where uid = {$_GET['soldier']}
```

Comment: my query is not wrong i have select all in there the query is not the problem i need to compare the url parameter to the database value and if they don't match redirect